# How to exclude associated table from findAll method in sequelize JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables, course,groups and students. Each course has multiple groups and each groups have multiple students. I want to select courses and its students but when I use findAll method its displays groups too like `[{courseName,courseCode,groups:[....,students:[...]]`. I just want `[{courseName,courseCode,students:[...]}}]` .
How can i exclude group table in findAll method?

These are my tables:

Course table:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class course extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      const { group } = models;

      this.hasMany(group, {
        foreignKey: "cid",
      });
    }
  }
  course.init(
    {
      cid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      cname: DataTypes.STRING,
      ccode: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ["cname", "ccode"],
        },
      ],
      sequelize,
      modelName: "course",
    }
  );
  return course;
};
```

Group table:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class group extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      const { teacher, studentgroup, student, subject, course } = models;

      this.hasMany(subject);

      this.belongsTo(course, {
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        foreignKey: "cid",
      });

      this.belongsTo(teacher, {
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        foreignKey: "tid",
      });
      this.belongsToMany(student, {
        through: studentgroup,
        foreignKey: "gid",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
      });
    }
  }
  group.init(
    {
      gid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      gno: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "group",
      timestamps: false,
    }
  );
  return group;
};
```

Student table

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class student extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      const { group, studentgroup, attendance, user, studentparent, parent } =
        models;

      this.belongsToMany(parent, {
        through: studentparent,
        foreignKey: "sid",
      });

      this.belongsTo(user, {
        foreignKey: "uid",
      });
      this.belongsToMany(group, {
        through: studentgroup,
        foreignKey: "sid",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
      });

      this.hasMany(attendance, {
        foreignKey: "sid",
      });
    }
  }
  student.init(
    {
      sid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "student",
    }
  );
  return student;
};
```

And this is my query:

```
await course.findAll({
      required: true,
      attributes: ["cname", "ccode"],
      include: [
        {
          required: true,
          model: models["group"],
          include: [
            {
              model: student,
              required: true,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
```

Comment: 1. Is it correct that a certain group can attend only one course? 2. Is it correct that a certain student can be in several groups?

Comment: @Anatoly 1-) Yes,sir. One group can only attend one course. 2-) One student can be in multiple groups but in different courses not on same courses.

Comment: Taking into account these relationships a course is linked to a student though 2 tables and so you can't link them through 1 table using `belongsToMany`. That means you can't get all students of a certain course automatically  You need to regroup these objects yourself for instance using `lodash` library.

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you for your answer,sir. I have one more question if you can help me. What is the correct way the associate these tables. I assoicated them like a chain but if you have better suggestion please share with me sir.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no simple solution here. It's better to get students for a certain course and not for all the courses at once.